# font awesome-webfont.woff2 file takes too long to load on page

Tags: css, html, font-awesome, webfonts

I am using `fontawesome` for my web application. I have the 2 files `fontawesome-webfont.woff2` and `lato-regular-webfont.woff2` saved locally.
These 2 files are taking too long to load the page. They take about 50 seconds to load which is a very slow loading time.
I am using `bootstrap 4` along with it.

I tried to load it  from `cdn`,but it still takes the same time to load.
Please see attached screenshot below.[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Probably this will help: https://www.grayboxpdx.com/blog/post/4-tips-to-faster-loading-google-fonts I know it's not a google font, but the idea is the same.

Comment: & the "Lato" - font you can fetch from the google fonts, probably these are buggy fonts or something like this.

Comment: How do you call your fonts? From HTML / CSS / JS?

Comment: Hi @joshii_h, the link you provided does not open in browser. It gives error "You don't have permission to access /blog/post/4-tips-to-faster-loading-google-fonts on this server."

Comment: @Ricks did you check your connection/limitations of Firewalls? because this site is provided by the USA and accessible to me from Switzerland. Try to open it with another network.

Comment: Hi @August, My `jquery.min.js` loads these fonts. I have not called them separately from my HTML. If you look in the above image provided in the question, the **initiator** for those 2 fonts is `jquery.min.js`

Comment: Hi @joshii_h, I tried it on different network which has no firewall. Could not open it. Gives the same error.

Comment: @Ricks: try to load them from HTML and see if loading times changes, also try it with <link rel="preload">